# Sending data fram from R to mySQL when the table is already in SQL?

Tags: mysql, r

I have some tables in my database that i am trying to populate with data that i have stored in R using library(RmySQL).  I am trying to send a dataframe of courses to a table named courses in the column course_names. Here is the code and mySQL functions I have been trying but none seem to work, although using dbWriteTable worked for a new table i called 'test', i want to send the data to a table that already exists.

```
ieCourses <- read.csv('IECourses.csv')
query <- "INSERT INTO courses(course_name) VALUES(ieCourses);" # This is wrong
rs <- dbSendQuery(mydb, query) # I feel this is the function to use but getting errors 

dbWriteTable(mydb, 'courses', ieCourses,overwrite=TRUE)
```

This is one of the errors i keep getting ... Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) :
could not run statement: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Comment: A while since I use R, but I think you must use something like dbSendUpdate or similar. Please try or check the doc of your library for a similar function.

Comment: Include `SHOW CREATE TABLE course`. The error message, after reading it, says there are foreign key constraints. You must correct this constrain in the same transaction.